# ASP.NET CORE Выдает ошибки, когда открываю index.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core, view

Пытаюсь понять asp.net, делаю все как на метаните  ( https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/3.3.php ), но мне выдает ошибки в index.cshtml. Как можно починить это?
[image: ошибки в index.cshtml]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Очевидно,  что либо using не прописан, либо не все зависимые пакеты установлены. Перечитайте статью внимательнее  :)